# Is it possible to use custom data types for MOSS user profile properties?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss, user-profile

We're wanting to add some properties to our MOSS user profiles and expose them to the people search. However, some of the data are more complex than just a string or choice or whatever. I've been looking around, and I can't seem to figure out if it's possible to create custom data types for use with the user profiles. Does anyone know if this is possible, and, if so, how to go about it?

More specifically, we'd like to add education data for our people. We kind of envision one education entry as including the degree / course of study, concentration / major, year, and institution. We'd also like for each user to be able to have multiple entries. It seems to me that, in an ideal, world, we'd be able to create a custom field control to handle the editing. Again, does anyone know if that sort of thing is possible?

Thanks a lot for any light you can shed on this subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As near as I can tell there is a fixed set of available types for user profile properties.  As noted [Property class reference docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.property.type.aspx), these appear to be: BigInteger, Binary, Boolean, Date, DateTime, Email, Float, HTML, Integer, Person, String, unique identifier, or URL.  I suppose binary, HTML, and perhaps String may have some potential merit for "roll your own" complex type-style property, but it appears difficult to do anything unhackish.

Comment: Wow. Hate to have my dreams shattered by a reference to the API docs. Thanks for turning that up.